# Scraping mobile android app using ARC Welder?

Tags: android, web-scraping, mobile-application

I am trying to figure out if I can scrape an android app in a similar way that I would a website. For example, in scraping a website I might use selenium to control a browser and collect data from the HTML code.

I have downloaded the chrome extension ARC Welder, which as far as I can tell simulates the app. However I cannot figure out how to "control" the app (i.e. press buttons, scroll, collect information such as prices of products).

Can anyone help or point to some useful information? I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.